# How can I decode this obfuscated javascript?

Tags: javascript, obfuscation, blogger, deobfuscation

I am in the process of setting up a blog through blogger.com and used a template from veethemes.com to get me started.

However, I noticed that there's an obfuscated script in the template and I'd prefer to know what it does to ensure that nothing untowards or unwanted is being done.

The code is as follows:

```
var _0x378a=["\x6B\x20\x45\x28\x73\x2C\x6E\x29\x7B\x79\x20\x73\x2E\x77\x28\x2F\x3C\x5C\x2F\x3F\x28\x3F\x21\x53\x5C\x73\x2A\x5C\x2F\x3F\x29\x5B\x61\x2D\x7A\x5D\x5B\x61\x2D\x54\x2D\x39\x5D\x2A\x5B\x5E\x3C\x3E\x5D\x2A\x3E\x2F\x4C\x2C\x22\x22\x29\x2E\x4B\x28\x2F\x5C\x73\x2B\x2F\x29\x2E\x31\x37\x28\x30\x2C\x6E\x2D\x31\x29\x2E\x5A\x28\x27\x20\x27\x29\x7D\x6B\x20\x31\x31\x28\x65\x2C\x74\x2C\x6E\x2C\x68\x2C\x63\x2C\x62\x2C\x71\x29\x7B\x35\x20\x72\x3D\x6A\x2E\x66\x28\x65\x29\x3B\x35\x20\x69\x3D\x6A\x2E\x66\x28\x6E\x29\x3B\x35\x20\x63\x3D\x63\x3B\x35\x20\x62\x3D\x62\x3B\x35\x20\x73\x3D\x22\x22\x3B\x35\x20\x6F\x3D\x72\x2E\x31\x39\x28\x22\x41\x22\x29\x3B\x35\x20\x61\x3D\x58\x3B\x35\x20\x70\x3D\x22\x22\x3B\x35\x20\x31\x36\x3D\x22\x75\x2E\x4D\x28\x57\x2E\x38\x2C\x20\x27\x31\x30\x27\x2C\x20\x27\x31\x32\x3D\x59\x2C\x20\x31\x33\x3D\x31\x34\x2C\x20\x31\x38\x3D\x78\x2C\x20\x31\x35\x3D\x78\x2C\x20\x4F\x2C\x20\x4E\x27\x29\x3B\x20\x79\x20\x50\x3B\x22\x3B\x49\x28\x6F\x2E\x51\x3E\x3D\x31\x29\x7B\x73\x3D\x27\x3C\x33\x20\x36\x3D\x22\x56\x2D\x55\x22\x3E\x3C\x61\x20\x38\x3D\x22\x27\x2B\x74\x2B\x27\x22\x3E\x3C\x41\x20\x36\x3D\x22\x52\x22\x20\x76\x3D\x22\x27\x2B\x6F\x5B\x30\x5D\x2E\x76\x2E\x77\x28\x2F\x73\x5C\x42\x5C\x64\x7B\x32\x2C\x34\x7D\x2F\x2C\x27\x73\x27\x2B\x31\x6F\x29\x2B\x27\x22\x20\x31\x71\x3D\x22\x22\x2F\x3E\x3C\x2F\x61\x3E\x3C\x2F\x33\x3E\x27\x3B\x61\x3D\x31\x73\x7D\x35\x20\x67\x3D\x27\x3C\x33\x20\x36\x3D\x22\x31\x72\x22\x3E\x3C\x33\x20\x36\x3D\x22\x31\x74\x22\x3E\x3C\x33\x20\x36\x3D\x22\x43\x22\x3E\x3C\x37\x20\x36\x3D\x22\x31\x61\x22\x3E\x27\x2B\x62\x2B\x27\x3C\x2F\x37\x3E\x3C\x37\x20\x36\x3D\x22\x31\x70\x22\x3E\x3C\x61\x20\x38\x3D\x22\x27\x2B\x74\x2B\x27\x23\x31\x6D\x22\x3E\x27\x2B\x63\x2B\x27\x3C\x2F\x61\x3E\x3C\x2F\x37\x3E\x3C\x2F\x33\x3E\x3C\x44\x3E\x3C\x61\x20\x38\x3D\x22\x27\x2B\x74\x2B\x27\x22\x3E\x27\x2B\x6E\x2B\x27\x3C\x2F\x61\x3E\x3C\x2F\x44\x3E\x3C\x33\x20\x36\x3D\x22\x43\x20\x31\x66\x22\x3E\x3C\x37\x20\x36\x3D\x22\x71\x22\x3E\x31\x65\x20\x31\x6E\x20\x27\x2B\x71\x2B\x27\x3C\x2F\x37\x3E\x3C\x37\x20\x36\x3D\x22\x68\x22\x3E\x31\x64\x20\x27\x2B\x68\x2B\x27\x3C\x2F\x37\x3E\x3C\x2F\x33\x3E\x3C\x2F\x33\x3E\x27\x2B\x73\x2B\x27\x3C\x33\x20\x36\x3D\x22\x31\x62\x22\x3E\x3C\x70\x3E\x27\x2B\x45\x28\x72\x2E\x6D\x2C\x61\x29\x2B\x27\x20\x5B\x2E\x2E\x2E\x2E\x2E\x5D\x3C\x2F\x70\x3E\x3C\x2F\x33\x3E\x3C\x2F\x33\x3E\x27\x3B\x72\x2E\x6D\x3D\x67\x7D\x3B\x75\x2E\x31\x63\x3D\x6B\x28\x29\x7B\x35\x20\x65\x3D\x6A\x2E\x66\x28\x22\x31\x67\x22\x29\x3B\x49\x28\x65\x3D\x3D\x31\x68\x29\x7B\x75\x2E\x31\x6C\x2E\x38\x3D\x22\x4A\x3A\x2F\x2F\x46\x2E\x47\x2E\x6C\x22\x7D\x65\x2E\x48\x28\x22\x38\x22\x2C\x22\x4A\x3A\x2F\x2F\x46\x2E\x47\x2E\x6C\x2F\x22\x29\x3B\x65\x2E\x48\x28\x22\x31\x6B\x22\x2C\x22\x31\x6A\x22\x29\x3B\x65\x2E\x6D\x3D\x22\x31\x69\x2E\x6C\x22\x7D","\x7C","\x73\x70\x6C\x69\x74","\x7C\x7C\x7C\x64\x69\x76\x7C\x7C\x76\x61\x72\x7C\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x7C\x73\x70\x61\x6E\x7C\x68\x72\x65\x66\x7C\x7C\x7C\x74\x61\x67\x7C\x63\x6F\x6D\x6D\x65\x6E\x74\x7C\x7C\x7C\x67\x65\x74\x45\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x74\x42\x79\x49\x64\x7C\x7C\x64\x61\x74\x65\x7C\x7C\x64\x6F\x63\x75\x6D\x65\x6E\x74\x7C\x66\x75\x6E\x63\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x7C\x63\x6F\x6D\x7C\x69\x6E\x6E\x65\x72\x48\x54\x4D\x4C\x7C\x7C\x7C\x7C\x61\x75\x74\x68\x6F\x72\x7C\x7C\x7C\x7C\x77\x69\x6E\x64\x6F\x77\x7C\x73\x72\x63\x7C\x72\x65\x70\x6C\x61\x63\x65\x7C\x32\x34\x7C\x72\x65\x74\x75\x72\x6E\x7C\x7C\x69\x6D\x67\x7C\x7C\x6D\x65\x74\x61\x7C\x68\x32\x7C\x73\x74\x72\x69\x70\x54\x61\x67\x73\x7C\x77\x77\x77\x7C\x76\x65\x65\x74\x68\x65\x6D\x65\x73\x7C\x73\x65\x74\x41\x74\x74\x72\x69\x62\x75\x74\x65\x7C\x69\x66\x7C\x68\x74\x74\x70\x7C\x73\x70\x6C\x69\x74\x7C\x69\x67\x7C\x6F\x70\x65\x6E\x7C\x72\x65\x73\x69\x7A\x61\x62\x6C\x65\x7C\x73\x63\x72\x6F\x6C\x6C\x62\x61\x72\x73\x7C\x66\x61\x6C\x73\x65\x7C\x6C\x65\x6E\x67\x74\x68\x7C\x61\x72\x74\x69\x63\x6C\x65\x5F\x69\x6D\x67\x7C\x62\x72\x7C\x7A\x30\x7C\x6D\x65\x64\x69\x61\x7C\x70\x6F\x73\x74\x7C\x74\x68\x69\x73\x7C\x73\x75\x6D\x6D\x61\x72\x79\x5F\x6E\x6F\x69\x6D\x67\x7C\x35\x35\x30\x7C\x6A\x6F\x69\x6E\x7C\x77\x69\x6E\x64\x6F\x77\x4E\x61\x6D\x65\x7C\x72\x6D\x7C\x77\x69\x64\x74\x68\x7C\x68\x65\x69\x67\x68\x74\x7C\x36\x30\x30\x7C\x74\x6F\x70\x7C\x70\x6F\x70\x75\x70\x7C\x73\x6C\x69\x63\x65\x7C\x6C\x65\x66\x74\x7C\x67\x65\x74\x45\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x74\x73\x42\x79\x54\x61\x67\x4E\x61\x6D\x65\x7C\x61\x72\x74\x69\x63\x6C\x65\x5F\x74\x61\x67\x73\x7C\x61\x72\x74\x69\x63\x6C\x65\x5F\x65\x78\x63\x65\x72\x70\x74\x7C\x6F\x6E\x6C\x6F\x61\x64\x7C\x6F\x6E\x7C\x70\x6F\x73\x74\x65\x64\x7C\x70\x6F\x73\x74\x5F\x6D\x65\x74\x61\x7C\x61\x74\x74\x72\x69\x5F\x62\x75\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x7C\x6E\x75\x6C\x6C\x7C\x56\x65\x65\x54\x68\x65\x6D\x65\x73\x7C\x64\x6F\x66\x6F\x6C\x6C\x6F\x77\x7C\x72\x65\x6C\x7C\x6C\x6F\x63\x61\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x7C\x63\x6F\x6D\x6D\x65\x6E\x74\x73\x7C\x62\x79\x7C\x37\x30\x30\x7C\x61\x72\x74\x69\x63\x6C\x65\x5F\x63\x6F\x6D\x6D\x65\x6E\x74\x73\x7C\x73\x74\x79\x6C\x65\x7C\x61\x72\x74\x69\x63\x6C\x65\x5F\x63\x6F\x6E\x74\x61\x69\x6E\x65\x72\x7C\x73\x75\x6D\x6D\x61\x72\x79\x69\x7C\x61\x72\x74\x69\x63\x6C\x65\x5F\x68\x65\x61\x64\x65\x72","","\x66\x72\x6F\x6D\x43\x68\x61\x72\x43\x6F\x64\x65","\x72\x65\x70\x6C\x61\x63\x65","\x5C\x77\x2B","\x5C\x62","\x67"];

eval(function(_0x6c60x1,_0x6c60x2,_0x6c60x3,_0x6c60x4,_0x6c60x5,_0x6c60x6)
{_0x6c60x5=function(_0x6c60x3){return (_0x6c60x3<_0x6c60x2?_0x378a[4]:_0x6c60x5(
parseInt(_0x6c60x3/_0x6c60x2)))+((_0x6c60x3=_0x6c60x3%_0x6c60x2)>35?String[_0x378a[5]]
(_0x6c60x3+29):_0x6c60x3.toString(36))};if(!_0x378a[4][_0x378a[6]]
(/^/,String)){while(_0x6c60x3--){_0x6c60x6[_0x6c60x5(_0x6c60x3)]=_0x6c60x4[_0x6c60x3]||_0x6c60x5(_0x6c60x3)};
_0x6c60x4=[function(_0x6c60x5){return _0x6c60x6[_0x6c60x5]}];_0x6c60x5=function(){return _0x378a[7]};_0x6c60x3=1;};
while(_0x6c60x3--){if(_0x6c60x4[_0x6c60x3])
{_0x6c60x1=_0x6c60x1[_0x378a[6]]( new 
 RegExp(_0x378a[8]+_0x6c60x5(_0x6c60x3)+_0x378a[8],_0x378a[9]),
_0x6c60x4[_0x6c60x3])}};return _0x6c60x1;}(_0x378a[0],62,92,_0x378a[3]
[_0x378a[2]](_0x378a[1]),0,{}));
```

I was able to decode the first part using [ddecode.com](http://www.ddecode.com) and came up with the following:

```
var _0x378a=["k E(s,n){y s.w(/<\/?(?!S\s*\/?)[a-z][a-T-9]*[^<>]*>/L,"").K(/\s+/).17(0,n-1).Z(' ')}k 11(e,t,n,h,c,b,q){5 r=j.f(e);5 i=j.f(n);5 c=c;5 b=b;5 s="";5 o=r.19("A");5 a=X;5 p="";5 16="u.M(W.8, '10', '12=Y, 13=14, 18=x, 15=x, O, N'); y P;";I(o.Q>=1){s='<3 6="V-U"><a 8="'+t+'"><A 6="R" v="'+o[0].v.w(/s\B\d{2,4}/,'s'+1o)+'" 1q=""/></a></3>';a=1s}5 g='<3 6="1r"><3 6="1t"><3 6="C"><7 6="1a">'+b+'</7><7 6="1p"><a 8="'+t+'#1m">'+c+'</a></7></3><D><a 8="'+t+'">'+n+'</a></D><3 6="C 1f"><7 6="q">1e 1n '+q+'</7><7 6="h">1d '+h+'</7></3></3>'+s+'<3 6="1b"><p>'+E(r.m,a)+' [.....]</p></3></3>';r.m=g};u.1c=k(){5 e=j.f("1g");I(e==1h){u.1l.8="J://F.G.l"}e.H("8","J://F.G.l/");e.H("1k","1j");e.m="1i.l"}","|","split","|||div||var|class|span|href|||tag|comment|||getElementById||date||document|function|com|innerHTML||||author||||window|src|replace|24|return||img||meta|h2|stripTags|www|veethemes|setAttribute|if|http|split|ig|open|resizable|scrollbars|false|length|article_img|br|z0|media|post|this|summary_noimg|550|join|windowName|rm|width|height|600|top|popup|slice|left|getElementsByTagName|article_tags|article_excerpt|onload|on|posted|post_meta|attri_bution|null|VeeThemes|dofollow|rel|location|comments|by|700|article_comments|style|article_container|summaryi|article_header","","fromCharCode","replace","\w+","\b","g"];
```

If I remove the script, the site breaks in certain places like Read More no longer cuts off the article on the home page and post headers are no longer visible, etc.

Any help in decoding this or tips on tools that may be available that would help me would be much appreciated.

Comment: http://www.jsnice.org/

Comment: Just so I don't make the same mistake again, could someone tell me why my question was downvoted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove `eval` in the code and throw it in the developer console.

[image: Example of deobfuscation]

Comment: Thank you, I never thought of doing this.
It looks like they obfuscated this script because it contained a method that's used to redirect to their site if the attribution isn't present.

`window.onload=function(){
 var e=document.getElementById("attri_bution");
 if(e==null){
  window.location.href="http://www.veethemes.com"
 }
 e.setAttribute("href","http://www.veethemes.com/");
 e.setAttribute("rel","dofollow");e.innerHTML="VeeThemes.com"
}`

sorry, I don't know how to style code in comments properly here.